# Android ADT text on button

Tags: android, xml, button

I've created a button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textBox"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
    android:text="@string/Button" />
```

But the last line should make the text on the button be: "Button".
But the text I'm getting is "@string".

Another Question:
The text in the button is aligned to right. How to make it CENTER?

Comment: Do you have a string by name Button in `strings.xml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you dont have any string named Button in strings.xml.
Do it this way

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textBox"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
    android:text="Button" />
```

or make a new string in your values/strings.xml as

```
 <string name="Button">Button</string>
```

And use it in your xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textBox"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
    android:text="@string/Button" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you written key name `Button` in `string.xml`??
do the modification as,

```
<string name="Button">Test_Button</string>
```

first check your xml file.
And to align it to center, set the property

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textBox"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
    android:text="@string/Button" />
```

Comment: I see the text: "But" on the button and it's aligned to right.
It is like half of the string is hidden...